# Error find object Spring JPA: "Error accessing field by reflection for persistent property"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, reflection

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "focusoc_orbit")
@Data
public class OrbitAdapter extends Adapter{

  @Id
  private String              id;

  ...

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  ...

}
```

And,

```
@Entity(name = "focusoc_conjunction")
@Data
public class ConjunctionAdapter extends Adapter {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long         id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
  private OrbitAdapter target;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "chaser_id")
  private OrbitAdapter chaser;

  ...
  public OrbitAdapter getTarget(){
    return target;
  }
  public void setTarget(OrbitAdapter target){
    this.target = target;
  }
  public String getChaserId(){
    return chaserId;
  }
  public void setChaser(OrbitAdapter chaser){
    this.chaser = chaser;
  }

  ...

}
```

Also I defined the Repository:

```
public interface ConjunctionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ConjunctionAdapter, Long> {
  public ConjunctionAdapter findByTargetAndChaserAndTimeOfCloseApproach(String target, String chaser, Date timeOfCloseApproach);
}
```

When I try to make the call,

```
ConjunctionAdapter c = conjunctionRepository.findByTargetAndChaserAndTimeOfCloseApproach(targetId, chaserId, timeOfCloseApproach());
```

It returns the error:

> org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.String
>   gcs.fds.focusoc.adapter.OrbitAdapter.id] by reflection for persistent
>   property [gcs.fds.focusoc.adapter.OrbitAdapter#id] : 02035A"

I tried a lot of differents solutions that I found but it does not work for me. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !

Changing the annotation @Data of the classes for @Table with the table name. So,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "focusoc_orbit")
public class OrbitAdapter extends Adapter{

  @Id
  private String              id;

  ...

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  ...

}
```

And,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "focusoc_conjunction")
public class ConjunctionAdapter extends Adapter {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long         id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
  private OrbitAdapter target;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "chaser_id")
  private OrbitAdapter chaser;

  ...
  public OrbitAdapter getTarget(){
    return target;
  }
  public void setTarget(OrbitAdapter target){
    this.target = target;
  }
  public String getChaserId(){
    return chaserId;
  }
  public void setChaser(OrbitAdapter chaser){
    this.chaser = chaser;
  }

  ...

}
```

And doing this it returns me the error,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [02035A] did not
>   match expected type [gcs.fds.focusoc.adapter.OrbitAdapter (n/a)]

So I added the annotation @Query into the Repository to specify which things has to be searched in the database,

```
public interface ConjunctionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ConjunctionAdapter, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT c FROM ConjunctionAdapter c WHERE c.target.id = :target AND c.chaser.id = :chaser AND c.timeOfCloseApproach = :timeOfCloseApproach")
  public ConjunctionAdapter findByTargetAndChaserAndTimeOfCloseApproach(String target, String chaser, Date timeOfCloseApproach);
}
```

And solved!